# Android App searches website and displays information

Tags: java, android, search, information-retrieval

How would I go about writing an Android application that will go online, search for, for example, the capital of a certain country (the user enters the name of the country in the search bar within the application), and display the name of the capital within the application?  Assuming that there is a website online that has this information - you can go on there, type in the name of a country and it will give you the capital - would it be possible to have my application search that website (obviously in the background) for the information and display it to the user in the application? Or maybe just get the information with a Google search?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: yes, it is possible.

The longer answer is - you need to find an API, that can help you with that.
Wolfram alpha may be exactly what you need. Have a look over here: http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/

Siri for iPhone is using the same API.

Comment: Happy to hear. Good luck! :)